# Split URL from beginning occurrence to end occurrence

Tags: ruby

If I have the following URL:

```
myString = "http://mywebsite.com/mySubdirectory"
```

and I only want to extract "`mywebsite.com`", how can I achieve this?

I need to take everything after the `http://` and everything before the end of "`.com.`"

I know that `myString.split('http://')` will leave `mywebsite.com/mySubdirectory`, but then how do I remove everything after the "`.com`" takes place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the right tools:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://mywebsite.com/mySubdirectory")
uri.host # => "mywebsite.com"
```

These days, EVERY decent language has code already written to tear apart a URI. Use those tools instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

[URI's documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html)

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, does URI have a method for extracting everything after the .com as well?

Comment: Ah, got it, that's uri.path

Comment: Yes, good, you looked at the documentation. :-) Use the tools. They're written to handle corner cases you won't expect but will make you insane when you run into them. Pay particular attention to how to (re)build URIs using URI. Being able to build them and follow the specs is very important.